# Do while Running more times

Tags: java, do-while

I have to get 1 to 3 answer if user puts invalid option do while should re run but problem is its re running three times. like if I put answer in 1 to 3 its giving correct result on other number it reprint loop three times.

```
char choice;
public void mainMartfunc() throws java.io.IOException{

        do{
            System.out.println("Login as:");
            System.out.println("    1. Customer");
            System.out.println("    2. Employee");
            System.out.println("    3. Owner");
            choice = (char) System.in.read();
            } while(choice < '1' || choice>'3');
        switch(choice){

         case '1':
             System.out.println("\tCustomer Menu:");
             break;

         case '2':
             System.out.println("\tEmployee Menu:");
             break;

         case '3':
            System.out.println("\tOwner Menu:");
            break;
        }
}
```

Comment: What do you think `System.in.read` does and why do you think so?

Comment: I read in complete reference Java, if you have to print menu this is best option thats why i implemented it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you press the enter key, two characters are generated: a carriage return `'\r'` and a line feed `'\n'`. And `System.in.read()` takes each character from the input, so you get three characters including the digit.

Trying using a Scanner instead. It will tokenize your input so you don't receive those whitespace characters.

```
java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
```

then change your `choice` assignment to something like this:

```
choice = input.next().charAt(0);
```

Comment: Very good explanation. Many do not realize the extra characters enter the input stream.

Comment: This have sort out my problem